# How to disable the red eye protection flash with sony powershot DSCWX80 or WX60?

Tags: flash, sony, camera-settings, powershot, red-eye

I want to DISABLE the extra flash that occurs when taking pictures of a group of people. Reason is, that people start looking away after they see the first flash, that occurs to remove the red eyes from photos.

What happens is that, the camera flashes quickly, then flashes again to take the picture. This ruins many many pictures as people do not understand when the picture is actually taken.

I want to disable this eye protection setting, but don't know how. For the auto settings if possible.

Someone got an idea?

Comment: Note that many cameras employ a preflash for metering, not just to help counter red-eye. It may not be possible to disable that (it usually _isn't_, in point-and-shoot cameras).

Comment: @mattdm that's just plain bad then. Nobody likes getting double flashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the online manual](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4447399112/EN/contents/07/01/07/07.html), you can turn off red-eye reduction, if that is what's causing your pre-flash:

1. Set the camera to shooting mode.
2. MENU -> Settings -> Shooting Settings -> [Red Eye Reduction] -> desired mode

You can set it to Auto, On, or Off.